# How to retain column index while we filter data in Angular Material data table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there any way we can invoke any function while we any value is entered in angular material data table filter field? As we want to maintain the column current index value while we filter for result. We are using Angular 6 for our project.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Yes we can invoke a function on value entering into angular material data table filter field like                                      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">

Answer (score 2):

If you're having a problem with accessing the correct index after filtering the data table, make sure you're using the `filteredData` property, and not the `data` property.

For example;

> data: this.dataSource.filteredData[index]